# ASP MVC Rounting, Remove /Areas/ Prefix from uri

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-page-application, asp.net-mvc-areas

By default Areas have a /Area/ routing prefix. For instance a Blog area would be :

```
/Areas/Blog/Blog/Show/myId
```

or

```
/Areas/{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}
```

The result is a really ugly and redundent uri for the web application. What I would like is something along the lines of :

```
/Blog/Show/myId
```

or

```
/{area / controller}/{action}/{id}
```

How can I achieve this ?

The reason I am using areas is because my 'blog' area is not a standard MVC application, but, a single-page application. It has a different project structure than the rest of the app, and so, I would like to just partition it into its own area.

**Edit : source for Area Registration**

```
public class BlogAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "Blog";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Blog_default",
            "Blog/{action}/{id}",
            new { controller ="blog", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

**Edit Source for Routeing**

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

**Edit**

After speaking /u/Eric Philips I have come up with a solution. The solution was rework my file structure to MVC compatible. Once I setup a controller and moved my index.cshtml page into a valid location, /Blog/ worked fine.

```
  public class BlogController : Controller
{
    // GET: Blog/Blog
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm so confused.  Areas are *MVC* specific.  Then you say you don't want an area prefix for a *non-mvc* application.  So what does areas in the MVC project have to do with the non-mvc application?

Comment: There is a single project. This project is a MVC application with support for SinglePageApplications. The SPA area contains about 5 cshtml pages and no controllers. It's structure is different from the rest of the app, so, I feel the need to place this code in an area.

It is in the area just fine, however, I have this ugly redundant routing path I have to use. I do not want to use the word Area, if I can help it.

Comment: I've actually never seens `/Areas/` when I create an area in my MVC applications (versions 3 and 5), the name of the area is the prefix without `/Areas/` (ie a blog area would be `/blog/{controller}/{action}`).

Comment: MVC5 here. /Areas/Blog/ works. /Blog/ does not.

Comment: I wouldn't know, you've provided absolutely no code.

Comment: What source code would you like me to provide ? This is a configuration issue not an exception or other coding error. That said, my configuration is 100% default. Code added

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58638/discussion-between-erik-philips-and-nventimiglia).